# Brasero and K3b: problems to burn data dvd's with files having spaces in its name

Tags: 10.04, burning, brasero, k3b, dvd-backup

I decided to move from Lucid to Maverick in my office computer and I wanted to make a backup of some files on DVD.

For this i tried Brasero and them k3b, both programs are not working with if the folder or files inside them have at least one space character. 
The most part of my files have space in its name so it would be a pain to rename all of them.

---

**01-** If I understood correctly, this problem is related to a kernel issues and not to these specific softwares am I right ?

**02-** I ask the archive manager to create a rar file broking the back up in files of 600Mb. In this way I was able to burn them but they are not accessible from archive manager. Is this related to the size I chose to broke them ?

**03-** Is there any other workaround or fix that I could use to make this backup on dvd's ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not being accessible has to do with not all the parts being present...if you want to be able to pull files out of a single part, there are several approaches. note:you can get files out of archive parts with the rar command line utility.  archive manager just doesn't understand how to do it.

You could do some shell script ninjitsu and wind up with archives of about that size that are not split which archive manager will understand.  Short of that, I don't know a way.

Answer (score 1):

Use an application like **kiso** to create an iso file of the data you want to backup. Then try burning that image onto the dvd.

Answer (score 0):

### How to find all files with the most typical characters with problem risks?

- I prefer basic system tools instead of add-on utilities.
- Here is a solution which can be extended to typical risks for your language
- (in this case: for German language)

  find /a*/ -type f  -regextype posix-egrep -regex "/a.*/.*[ä-äö-öü-üß-ß\ \,\;\?].*"  -print

This would look up all files in the file trees starting with a directory name: /a...

You would see all files listed which include a space character,

or one of;   ä  ö  u  ß   ,  ;   ?

### Then often bulk rename is required.

This could be done this way:

Rename files/bulk = (inside CURREN(!)directory)

(-n =simulat.without rename)

===    rename -v -n 's/^xb-/uxb-/'  xb*  ; ls -l ./   ;

Above: For start of file names.

Is to adapt to the task, e.g. below for an inner character group of a file name, and now not similuation -n but really doing the rename:

===    rename -v 's/have/had/'  *have*  ; ls -l ./   ;

### All this could surely be improved.

But for normal needs it should do the job.

I did not yet succeed to implement how trailing line feeds can be detected. 
This fault might occur when saving files with the editor KATE.

I had only a small case number of this error. So the debug message of K3b was sufficient to detect these files, 1 by 1 with repeating burn attempts.

Perhaps somebody with better knowledge for this will add here how to detect in the way like above also trailing line feeds in file names? (Hence just by extending the regular expression in the command "find ...".)